# Find the closed form of $\tan\frac{\pi }{64}$ by using the number $2$ only?

Tags: calculus

How do I find the closed form of $ \tan\frac{\pi }{64}$ by using the number $2$ only ?

Comment: What does "by using the number $2$ only" mean?

Comment: What do you mean with a closed form?

Comment: the closed form contains the number 2 only

Comment: First, You can use the fact that $\displaystyle tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}}$. Then use the fact that $\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}}$ to get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean this here
$\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}}$?

Answer (score 1):

By using the half angle formulas, you should be able to decompose $\tan(\frac{\pi}{64})$ into $\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{16})}{\cos(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{16})}$ and then proceed as indicated here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi16.html